# Editing WP Plugin

Tags: posts, wp-list-pages

I have a plugin that will has a dropdown box to select a post, but I want to change it so that it will select a page. Here is the original code.  What do i need to change?

```
<?php
    function getPostsList () {
        global $wpdb;

        return $shows = $wpdb->get_results
            ("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts where post_type = 'post' and post_status = 'publish'" );
    }

    function page_selector ($name) {
        $value = get_option ($name);
        $posts = getPostsList ();

        echo "<select class='span7' name='{$name}'><option></option>";

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $selected = ($post->ID == $value) ? 'selected' : '';
            echo "<option value='{$post->ID}' {$selected}>{$post->post_title}</option>";
        }

        echo "</select>";
    }

    $vars = array (
        'sf_tos_page',
        'sf_policy_page',
        'sf_support_page',
        'sf_earnings_page',
        'sf_disclaimer_page',
        'powered_by_link',
        'follow_up_email_subject',
        'follow_up_email'
    );

    foreach ($vars as $var) {
        if (isset ($_POST [$var])) {
            update_option ($var, $_POST [$var]);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: This is clearly not your code. It is not advisable to make changes to plugins (or themes or core file). You'd be better of to contact the plugin author about this.

Comment: I did, but they refuse to change it... Even after I explained to them, that this should linked to a page instead of a post.... If I can get the changes to work, I will submit the code to them so I do not have to change it every time they have an update. Any help would be appreciated....

Comment: In your `SELECT` statement, change `post_type` from `post` to `page`